# Как использовать DiffUtil в RendererRecyclerViewAdapter

Tags: android, recyclerview, recyclerview.adapter

Для простоты работы с `RecyclerView` использую готовую библиотеку [RendererRecyclerViewAdapter](https://github.com/vivchar/RendererRecyclerViewAdapter), по семплам добавил `Renderer`, `Model`, `ViewHolder`.

Для обновления списка использую два метода:

```
mAdapter.setItems(myList);
mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Но я хочу использовать [DiffUtil](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/util/DiffUtil.html) чтобы автоматически добавить анимации удаления, добавления и перемещения ячеек.

Как мне это сделать при использовании этой библиотеки?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Данная библиотека уже поддерживает `DiffUtil`

1) В каждом вашем классе унаследованном от `ItemModel` добавьте реализацию методов `equals()` и `hashcode()`;

2) Вызовете метод `enableDiffUtil()` после инициализации адаптера

```
...
RendererRecyclerViewAdapter adapter = new RendererRecyclerViewAdapter();
adapter.enableDiffUtil();
...
```

3) Уберите вызов метода `notifyDataSetChanged()`

После вызова `setItems(myList)` библиотека автоматически вызовет `DiffUtil`, больше ничего не надо делать.